# Show Tag on each products in product list in home or category page in prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I want to print tag on each product thumbnail in the product list of my prestashop store. I tried adding the following code in product-list.tpl

```
<span class="tptag btn btn-danger">
    {foreach from=Tag::getProductTags($product.id_product) key=k item=v}
        {foreach from=$v item=value}
            <a href="{$link->getPageLink('search', true, NULL, "tag={$value|urlencode}")}">{$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'}</a>
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
</span>
```

But it fetching nothing. How can i display the tags.?

Comment: Version of PrestaShop?

Comment: Just tested and it works, It's trivial but have you add the tags to products :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span class="tptag btn btn-danger">
    {foreach Tag::getProductTags($product.id_product) as $k=>$tags}
        {foreach $tags as $tag}
            <a href="{$link->getPageLink('search', true, NULL, [tag =>$tag|urlencode])}">{$tag|escape:html:'UTF-8'}</a>
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
</span>
```